# Which is better for a multi-process website, child_process or cluster?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js application that I'm working on and before I get too far into it I want to ensure I'm using the right method to achieve my desired result.

Essentially I have a single parent process which will serve an index.html which acts as a landing page and will provide navigation to various modules. I want each module to be running as a separate process and when the parent receives a request for say "site.com/modulename/request_format_specific_to_each_module" it will send the http servers response object to the appropriate modules process and allow that module to handle the response from that point. I do however need to retain textual module->parent communication as well.

My question is, would I be better served using "child_process.fork()" or "cluster.fork()"?

EDIT: 
I know cluster can allow multiple processes to listen on the same port, but can separate processes be made to listen to SPECIFIC requests on said port?
i.e.

```
site.com --> main parent process
site.com/module1/request --> process for module1
site.com/module2/request --> process for module2
```

... Or is using child_process and having the parent filter and route requests the better method for doing this?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I don't believe the questions are quite the same (Though correct me if I am wrong). I understand that cluster.fork can have all processes listening on the same port, but I'm referring to only one process listening for requests and routing the request to the appropriate process then allowing THAT process to respond. I feel the suggested question is similar, but not quite close enough to be a duplicate, nor does it answer my question. I will add an edit to my question further clarifying.

Comment: True, I'll try and find the appropriate duplicate, because I think I remember this question being asked before. You might also like to check out the related questions to the right, which might answer your question.